# How can I calculate the morphological similarity between sentences?

Tags: computational-linguistics, morphology, parsing

For my bachelor thesis i am probing various text similarity metrics for how much they incorporate different aspects of sentences.

To get those aspects I use datasets that are annotated for semantic similarity, use a syntax tree parser to calculate a syntactic similarity measure and calculate BLEU to get lexical overlap.

I would now also like to include some measure of a morphological similarity between sentence pairs.
I have looked at the word embeddings intended to incode morphological data that are described here: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N15-1140.pdf (I would then either pool them for the sentence or find alignments by some strategy).

I could also directly compare morphological (sub-)tags in some way.

However, for these and other approaches I would need at least some data annotated with morphological tags, which the data annotated for semantic similarity that i use is not.

Is it reasonable to trust an automated morphological parser for that?

And are there any other ideas to calculate a morphological similarity between senteces?